# Run sqlite3 command inline

Tags: sqlite, command-line-interface

This may sound odd but I have 15 databases within different folders and I wish to update them all.
I have made a text file for me to easily copy the sql file that I need to import in to each root folder and load the DB, so I can just copy and paste each to CLI and then I can then type the following in to each one.
`sqlite> .read backup.sql`

and it imports the data I need it too...I then exit (CTRL + Z) and run the next one...

However, can I easily run something like
`sqlite3 database.db > .read backup.sql`

So I can effectively run the whole thing from one command line?

Comment: Your use of `>` is quite confusing. Please explain your reasoning.

Comment: Do you want to call sqlite and directly provide the file to read on the Os commandline (in contrast to the commandline of the tool)? Is that what you try?

Comment: I think I've figured it out... using sqlite3 database.db ".read backup.sql"

Comment: Thought something similar, and as I mentioned, the `>` was getting in the way. Please create an answer yourself or delete the question.

Comment: `sqlite3 database.db < backup.sql` works too.